# Where is the static constant in the enum stored in the swift?

Tags: swift, computer-science

`enum`s are stored in stack segment by OS. And `static variable`s are located in Data segment when app is begining.
Then, what is location of static constants in enum which is declared in ViewController?

for example, from this code

```swift
class mainViewController: UIViewController {
    enum Constants {
        static let height: CGFloat = 16
    }

    // ...
}
```

What is the location of `height` and `height`'s address?